# Highchats xAxis month

Tags: angular, highcharts

I use the Highcharts library to illustrate diagrams in my project.
My problem is that on the xAxis axis, I would like to display only the last 3 active months and nothing else.
I think I need to use the Date object but I can't display what I want.

My code:

```
toto = 'tetoto';
  idProducts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  date = new Date;

  chart = new Chart({
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',  
      height: 220,
    },
    title: {
      text: undefined
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
  },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: undefined
      },
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: this.toto,
        data: this.idProducts,
        pointStart: this.date, 
    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 * 24
      }, 
    ],
  }  as any);
```

thanks

Comment: Hi @HCP, Could you provde me with a sample of your data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data before creating the chart or use, after chart is loaded,  `setExtremes` method for x-axis to restrict the visible plot area to 3 months period.

```
    events: {
        load: function(){
            var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
                oneMonth = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

            xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.dataMax - oneMonth * 3, xAxis.dataMax);
        }
    }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8t9skw7m/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: I misspoke sry.
I wish that 
pointStart = date - 3 months
pointMiddle = date - 2 months
pointEnd = today's date
3 months in my xAxis 1 per month and i would like to put 1 point per week.

Comment: Hi @HCP, So you need to only create the right data. Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k1pe3tan/